# Nginx reverse proxy gives “502 Bad Gateway”

Tags: python, nginx, flask

My reverse proxy server gives “502 Bad Gateway”. But it perfectly works when I set port 5000. No other ports are working except port 5000.

I have a flask application, which is running on port 8888. If I directly hit on port 8888 (without nginx), it works. I can't figure out why other ports are not working.

Here is my default file:

```
    *upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8888; # Only port # 5000 works
    }
   server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
    }*
```

I have searched in google, but did not found any useful solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you start Flask? Do you use e.g. Gunicorn? Is this all on your machine or in the cloud? Which hoster?

Comment: Hi J.G, I am using our shared Ubuntu machine not cloud. Yes I am using Gunicorn, by this command (gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8888 wsgi:app). IP:8888 works. Even nginx works for port 5000. One think, some other people are also working here with different user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

The problem was that when I change the port number in the default configuration file, the change was not updated by my Linux machine. I grep the nginx and found that nginx always get my old port number (port 5000) not updated one.

I have edited the default config by vim command (sudo vim default) and then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not super familiar with the above used syntax, but I maintain quite some Flask applications with nginx as reverse proxy.

I am suspicious about this line

```
proxy_pass http://backend;
```

Given the above information, I would write a configuration as following:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8888;
}
```

Also, I'd strongly suggest that you set a `server_name` and also use SSL encryption. This means, also serve for port 443.

If you still encounter problems, please have a look at both nginx error log ( at my Ubuntu machine that is `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and in the Flask/Gunicorn error log.

Comment: Thank you J.G. I will take a look  Flask/Gunicorn error file. I have tried the way you mention above. Actually, strange thing is that my nginx only work if I set port 5000!  I put my default config under this location (nginx/sites-enabled/). Some people suggest creating a config file under conf.d. Where did you put your configuration file? Is it under etc/nginx/sites-enabled or nginx/conf.d file? Did you update your nginx.conf ?

Comment: I put all my config files into `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and then symlink them into `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` (and then reload nginx). I did not have to change `nginx.conf`. When you say, it works with port 5000? What works? What do you see? You need to find out where this 5000 is coming from. You could grep both the nginx config directory and your flask / gunicorn directories for this value and try to find out what sets this port.

Comment: I write a "hello world" program using flask. My nginx listens on port 80 and pass a proxy to a port. Work means that I can see "hello word" on the browser when I set reverse proxy 5000. For other port like 8888 it shows me 502 Bad gateway. I will grep both directories for port 5000.

Comment: flask open in port 5000 by default. You can change that when you start the app in your python script:
```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8888)
```